# Groff: how to successfully compile a manpage, containing Cyrillic in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, cyrillic, manpage, groff, troff

Colleagues, please tell me what arguments you need to set for groff so that it compiles the manpage writed in Cyrillic, in UTF-8 encoding.

I have a number of pages written in markdown and converted to nroff by the lowdown utility.
Groff version 1.19.2 for FreeBSD 11.4 amd64.

If I run with the options like **'groff -man -Tutf8'**, then he is very unhappy:
*standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 157

standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 144

standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 151

standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 146

standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 152

standard input:3: warning: can't find character with input code 149

standard input:4: warning: can't find character with input code 143*

How do I get groff to work with such pages?

Comment: Please share input string related to warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you use specific characters, you must use a font that contains them. Depending a bit on your system, that may be dejavu for example.

```
groff -man -Tutf8 -f dejavu
```